# Email address validation for MS Access table

Tags: validation, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

My table has the following validation in the "Validation Rule" Section of an Access table that keeps most the email addresses I enter clean:

> Like "?*@?*.??*" And Not Like "*[!a-z@=.^_$%!#&'`{|}*?~/-]*" and .

However, it still lets in stuff like Bla.Bla@testing.co.u

I found this link for JavaScript. It does a much better job than mine and would filter out the kind of email addresses mentioned above. [How to validate an email address in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript?rq=1)

How would it look for MS Access? Function or Validation rule are fine just interested to know if it is possible.

Comment: Another one that creeps in are also emails like bla@web.d instead of bla@web.de.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegExp is the best way to validate an email.

Here's a VBA function that does it, using the RegExp in the answer that you linked

```
Public Function Email_Validation(ByVal strEmail As String) As Boolean


    Const strRexExp As String = "^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@""]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@""]+)*)|("".+""))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$"

    Dim objRG As New RegExp
    Dim IsValid As Boolean

    On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    strEmail = Trim(strEmail)

    objRG.IgnoreCase = True
    objRG.Global = True
    objRG.Pattern = strRexExp

    IsValid = objRG.Test(strEmail)


Exit_Function:
    Email_Validation = IsValid
    Exit Function

Err_Handler:
    IsValid = False
    MsgBox "Email_Validation Error: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Function
End Function
```

You have to add a reference to your project : `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions X.X`

When you want to validate, call the function using

```
Email_Validation("Bla.Bla@testing.co.u")
```

it will return TRUE or FALSE (false in that case)

Comment: For people looking its Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 Ms Access 2013 at least

Answer (score 0):

Hey Thomas thanks alot your function really helped. For everyone else ive just posted how i implemented your function.

```
Public Function Email_Validation(ByVal strEmail As String) As Boolean


    Const strRexExp As String = "^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@""]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@""]+)*)|("".+""))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$"

    Dim objRG As New RegExp
    Dim IsValid As Boolean

    On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    strEmail = Trim(strEmail)

    objRG.IgnoreCase = True
    objRG.Global = True
    objRG.Pattern = strRexExp

    IsValid = objRG.Test(strEmail)


Exit_Function:
    Email_Validation = IsValid
    Exit Function

Err_Handler:
    IsValid = False
    MsgBox "Email_Validation Error: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Function
End Function

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM Emails WHERE DateAdded =#" & Date & "#;")
Dim Email As String

'Check to see if the table has any rows
If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
    rs.MoveFirst 'Unnecessary in this case, but still a good habit
    Do Until rs.EOF = True
        'Perform an edit
       If Email_Validation(rs!Emails) = True Then
        rs.MoveNext
       Else
        rs.Delete
       End If
    rs.MoveNext
    Loop
Else
MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset."
End If

rs.Close 'Close the recordset
Set rs = Nothing 'Clean up
```

Comment: The where statement in the SQL is just to cut down the number of records brought back